# How to write a virtual framebuffer driver for Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, kernel, framebuffer, kernel-extension

So, I want to write a virtual monitor driver for mac. This is something similar to what screen recycler app does. I've been reading so many resources about driver programming and kext in general and I've done the basic iokit driver tutorial from apple, but where to go from here?

The tutorial provides a very basic understanding of drivers but to my use case, it is definitely not sufficient. I know we have to implement the IOframebuffer header but I have no idea about the rest? Also the IOframebuffer header has quite some complex methods and I'm not well aware of how to implement those. Can someone provide me with some useful pointers as to what needs to be done?

I've already seen this question

[Pointers to creating virtual monitor drivers for OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658428/pointers-to-creating-virtual-monitor-drivers-for-os-x)

these repos,

https://github.com/tSoniq/displayx

https://github.com/mkernel/EWProxyFramebuffer

But the problem is, both the projects doesn't work in MAC OS 10.12 since they were not updated for a long time.

I'm looking for some guidelines that I need to follow to write such a driver and apple docs aren't really helping.

Comment: Hi @Arvind, I am currently looking for a similar thing. What have you ended up doing?

Comment: Maybe this very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597482/creating-a-virtual-display-on-macos-programmatically) helps you out.